# Common Lisp Weak References?

Tags: common-lisp, weak-references

Is there a portable (across implementations) way to create weak references in CL?
If not, what alternative should I use to avoid memory leaks caused by unneeded listeners kept alive solely by being subscribed to events?
In my particular case, said listeners are used to implement functional reactive nodes (i.e. no side effects, only useful for their stored values) so manual unsubscription would be quite inelegant.

Comment: Maybe this: http://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-garbage/

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic for Stack OVerflow: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  You might try asking on comp.lang.lisp, the lispforum site, or #lisp.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I think his question is reasonably clear -- he's writing reactive code, and his handlers are preventing his nodes from getting garbage collected.  The easy solution would be to use weak references, and he's asking how to write them portably.

Comment: @jch Yes, it's not particularly unclear.  As I mentioned, it's really boils down to a library request, and while library requests are useful in the broader sense, they're not a great fit for Stack Overflow.  It's much harder to evaluate whether an answer is right or wrong;  there are lots of potential answers;  and answers getting outdated is a serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

Weak references were not standardised by ANSI, and while most implementations have a way to create weak references, the abstractions provided are different.  For example, CMUCL, CLISP and SBCL all provide weak references ("weak pointers"), while Franz has weak vectors and Clozure has value-weak hashtables.

There are libraries that claim to provide a portable interface to weak pointers on a range of implementations.  I don't know how good they are.